# How do I store input from the user in an array?

Tags: c#, loops

So, I have to ask the user for a set of 5 to 15 numbers until they enter an EOP. How do I save those numbers in an array? Using those numbers from the array, I will have to do some other stuff, like listing them, finding the average, etc. But I can't figure out how to save the numbers entered by the user into the array.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a set of grades. Min 5 grades, Max 15 grades:");
Console.WriteLine("To show the menu, enter -99");

for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Enter grade:");
  strGrades = Console.ReadLine();
  intGrades = Int32.Parse(strGrades);

  if (intGrades == -99)
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine("1. Number of values in the array\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("2. List the values in the array\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("3. Average\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("4. Delete a specific value \n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("5. Clear all the values in the array\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("6. Change a specific value\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("7. Exit");

    strChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    Choice = Int32.Parse(strChoice);

    int[] arr = new int[15];

    for (int x = 0; x <= arr.Length; x++)
    {
      arr[x] = intGrades;
      arr[x] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      intCounter++;

      if (intGrades == -99)
      {
        intCounter--;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. If you're looking for help, you should post code that does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use List

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a set of grades. Min 5 grades, Max 15 grades:");
Console.WriteLine("To show the menu, enter -99");

List<int> lstGrades=new List<int>();

for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Enter grade:");
  strGrades = Console.ReadLine();
  intGrades = Int32.Parse(strGrades);

  lstGrades.Add(intGrades);

  if (intGrades == -99)
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine("1. Number of values in the array\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("2. List the values in the array\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("3. Average\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("4. Delete a specific value \n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("5. Clear all the values in the array\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("6. Change a specific value\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("7. Exit");

    strChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    Choice = Int32.Parse(strChoice);

    /*int[] arr = new int[15];

    for (int x = 0; x <= arr.Length; x++)
    {
      arr[x] = intGrades;
      arr[x] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      intCounter++;
      if (intGrades == -99)
      {
         intCounter--;*/
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

Keep in mind that for List you need to use System.Collections.Generic

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

So... the program:

```
static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "To show the menu, enter -99" );
            Console.WriteLine( "Please enter a set of grades. Min 5 grades, Max 15 grades: " );
            List<int> gradesList =new List<int>();
            bool exit=false;
            do
            {
                int x = 0;
                int.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out x );
                switch( x )
                {
                    case -99:
                        exit = true;
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine( "Please insert integer values:" );
                        break;
                    default:
                        gradesList.Add( x );
                        break;
                }
            } while( !exit );
            ShowMenu();

        }
        static void ShowMenu()
        {
            bool exit=false;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "1. Number of values in the array" );
                Console.WriteLine( "2. List the values in the array" );
                Console.WriteLine( "3. Average" );
                Console.WriteLine( "4. Delete a specific value" );
                Console.WriteLine( "5. Clear all the values in the array" );
                Console.WriteLine( "6. Change a specific value" );
                Console.WriteLine( "7. Exit" );

                int x = 0;
                int.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out x );

                switch( x )
                {
                    case 1:
                        //number of values in the array
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //list of values in the array
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //average
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        //delete a specific value
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        //clear all values in the array
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        //change a specific value
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        exit = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid option");
                        break;
                }
            } while( !exit );
        }
```